# Showing Status-field as dropdown in Directus 7?

Tags: directus

is there a way to make a Status-field display like an *dropdown*/*select-box* instead of radio-buttons? I have about 10 status' and I would like to display them as a *dropdown* instead.

I wasn't able to find anything about this in the documentation, did I miss something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not the "core" status interface,  but you can duplicate [the code](https://github.com/directus/app/tree/master/src/interfaces/status) and create a custom one in a `select` instead. The new interface would go into the [custom extensions directory in the API](https://github.com/directus/api/tree/master/public/extensions/custom/interfaces). Should be pretty straightforward.

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/interfaces.html

Comment: I've just tried this, but I'm getting an error: `this.interface is undefined; registerInterface input.vue:157`. Also `input.js` can't be downloaded (according to my browser's network tab). Any ideas?